# Is it possible to add annotations to static factorymetods with lombok

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

If I create a class like

```
@Value
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "of", onConstructor = @__(@JsonCreator))
public class Test {
    String value;
}
```

The onConstructor properties is added to the constructor (which makes sense). However I need to add an annotations to the factory metod. Is this possible?

My root problem is trying to make

```
{
    "test": 2018
}
```

deserialize to:

```
SomeJavaClass:
 private final Test test
```

This doesn't work because of the ConstructorProperties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the annotation on the static factory method would be the most reasonable thing to do when both `staticName` and `onConstructor` are set. In that case, the regular constructor becomes `private` and, thus, cannot be used from elsewhere (except for ugly reflection tricks). Therefore, annotations only make sense on the static factory method in most cases.

However, this is not Lombok's current behavior, and there is no way to configure Lombok differently. I suggest you [create a feature request at GitHub](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues).
However, be aware that the `onX` feature is an experimental feature, so this feature request may be declined or deferred.